# Find - не функция

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот

Создаю бота для дискорда и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
при попытке найти одинаковое название в базе с аргументом вылазит ошибка. Код:

```
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const users = require('./users.json');
const request = require('prequest');

if(args[2] == users.find(ch => ch.name === args[2])) <---
```

казалось бы всё нормально, но вот, что происходит:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: users.find is not a function
```

Очень прошу помощи!

Comment: Скорее всего в `users.json` не массив. Что там находится?

Comment: Просто {}. При вводе команды создаётся игрок и статы:
    users[uid] ={
          name: args[2],
       pin: args[3],
       balance: 0,
            };

Comment: ну так `.find` - метод массива, у объекта такого нету. Как вариант, вместо `{}` написать `[]` или создать ключ и делать `.find` по нему

Comment: Я на самом деле не очень сильно разбираюсь. Мог бы дать пример?

Comment: О, да, спасибо за наводку. Действительно было всё проще, чем я думал.

Answer (score 1):

В users.js вместо {} надо было поставить [] и всё действительно заработало.